# How can I make navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition work on deployed app

Tags: heroku, geolocation, js, react

I am building a Next-js app that should work only within a specific geo-radius. I am using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition to get the current location of the user. When I test the app locally, it works well and pops up the allow location request on the browser. However, when I deploy it to Heroku, this feature doesn't work. I am unable to get the location of the user.

This is part of the code

```
            const geoLocation = () => {
            if (!navigator.geolocation){
                setStatus('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
            }else{
                setStatus('Locating...');
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                    setStatus(null);
                    setLat(position.coords.latitude);
                    setLng(position.coords.longitude);
                }, () => {
                    setStatus('Unable to retrieve your location');
                })
            }
        }
```

Please help figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a server side code or client side? What does the browser console say?

Comment: It is client side, when I try logging geolocation on console, it returns null.